# Docker and Kafka Connection Issue Kafka-Python

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I have a kafka cluster running in docker which I create with the .yml file below:

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.4.0"
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports:
      - '32181:32181'
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 32181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"  
      
  kafka:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.4.0"
    hostname: kafka
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
      - '29092:29092'
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:32181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:32181
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"  
      
  schema-registry:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:latest"
    hostname: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: zookeeper:32181
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"  
      
  kafdrop:
    image: "obsidiandynamics/kafdrop"
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: kafka:29092
      JVM_OPTS: "-Xms32M -Xmx64M"
      SERVER_SERVLET_CONTEXTPATH: "/"
    depends_on:
      - kafka
```

I then have a simple producer not in Docker just on my machine that I am trying to produce messages to the cluster. The producer file is:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import time


topicName = 'myTestTopic'

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092', 'kafka:29092'])


while True:
    message = producer.send(topicName, value=b'Hello World')

    metadata = message.get()
    print(metadata.topic)
    print(metadata.partition)
    time.sleep(5)
```

When I run the file and the cluster is running on docker all I get is this error

```
    raise Errors.NoBrokersAvailable()
kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable
```

Any help to resolve this issue would be great

Comment: Remove `'kafka:29092'` from your code. You only have one broker, so you don't need a list